# Cross correlation c++ and matlab

Tags: c++, matlab, opencv, cross-correlation

I'm trying to do a cross correlation in C++. Problem is that I'm not getting same result in matlab.

**C++ code**

```
float telo[5] = {-1, 0, 1, 2, 3};
Mat prueba(1, 5, CV_32F, telo);
float telo2[3] = { 0, 1, 2 };
Mat prueba2(1, 3, CV_32F, telo2);
Mat result;
matchTemplate(prueba, prueba2, result, CV_TM_CCORR);
Result: 2048.0004882812500 2.660783784765e-314#DEN -6.2774385622041925e+066
```

**Matlab code:**

```
a = [-1,0,1,2,3]
b = [0,1,2]
xcorr2(a,b)
Result: -2 -1 2 5 8 3 0
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I try your C++ code sample with OpenCV 3 I get the following result, as expected:

```
2, 5, 8
```

Which is the same as the Matlab solution, but without the tails.

---

**Edit:**

To obtain the same result as with Matlab you can add some zero-padding to your input data. Do it manually in your data:

```
float telo[9] = {0, 0, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 0};
Mat prueba(1, 9, CV_32F, telo);
```

Or a more generic solution (which should also work with 2D data) would be to call

```
copyMakeBorder(prueba, prueba, prueba2.rows - 1, prueba2.rows - 1, prueba2.cols - 1, prueba2.cols - 1, cv::BORDER_CONSTANT);
```

before `matchTemplate`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I am using opencv 2.49, so is there wrong implementation or why is output different? Is there any way how to obtain exactly same output as matlab (with head and tail of the sequence)?

Comment: I don't know why you are seeing different results. Did you try with exactly the code you posted or is that a simplified example? I updated my answer to explain how to obtain also the tails.

Comment: I have copied exactly the same source code from my main function and pasted it here. Is there any rule how many zeros should I use? Because matlab does the padding itself.

Comment: Yes the rule is: add (length of prueba2 - 1) on each side. My call to `copyMakeBorder` does exactly that.